# Generate a random filename in C++

Tags: c++, opencv, random, filenames

I am working on an object-detection application in C++. And I store each false negative images, so I need a random file name generator, which should not duplicate them.

I am currently using `tmpnam`, but it does not guarantee uniqueness, so files could be overwritten, because all files are stored in same folder.

I am looking for any other way to generate unique file names.

Comment: Is there any reason a time stamp in the file name wouldn't work?

Comment: Generate a GUID (Global Unique Identifier) and use that within the name of the file.

Comment: `tmpnam` **does** guarantee uniqueness, as best as can be on a system where some other process can be creating files at the same time as yours is. As long as nobody else is writing to your directory and you haven't created more than `TMP_MAX` files (`TMP_MAX` must be at least 25), you won't get duplicate names.

Comment: @PeteBecker: So you are guaranteed 25 unique file names? Now that doesn't sound like a terribly useful function. Using a GUID as a file name is already better than that, and it doesn't suffer from collisions due to concurrent invocations.

Comment: @IInspectable - shrug. `tmpnam` already exists; it will provide **at least** 25 unique names; and it's portable. If it doesn't do what you want, by all means, roll your own.

Comment: @IInspectable - "[a GUID] doesn't suffer from collisions due to concurrent invocations" - while it's true that a GUID is **very unlikely** to be a duplicate, it is not guaranteed. Please don't overstate your case; that makes it sound like you're setting out a political position rather than a technical one.

Comment: @PeteBecker  I have just checked that `TMP_MAX` is equal to 238328 which is great. But, if I run the application several times, is  `tmpnam` still guarantee unique file names for same directory?

Comment: @koruj - it's 238328 with the particular runtime library that you used; it may vary with other compilers. Nevertheless, 25 is just the minimum, and it would surprise me if any system provided a mere 25 unique names. And, yes, it checks the names in the directory to ensure that it isn't providing a duplicate name. The only reason it isn't guaranteed to be unique is the possibility that someone else created a file with that name **after** `tmpnam` checked; there's a very narrow time window for that. And that's a problem with **any** system for generating names, including systems that use GUIDs.

Comment: @PeteBecker I understand now. Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: You can also consider static counter in your program: increment it after saving each new file and generate file names with this counter value.

Comment: @PeteBecker: A UUID is guaranteed to be unique to a system up to 2^14 UUIDs per 100-ns timestamp. And that's if you are using the network adapter's MAC address. If you aren't using the MAC address you have an additional 48 bits of entropy. Using a UUID in place of `tmpnam` has an additional benefit: You do not need to touch the disk, and waste potentially lots of time for very little return. If you need a solution that is guaranteed to work without any restrictions, use a UUID, and call a file creation function that will fail, if the file already exists. Rinse. Repeat.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using GUID's. As stated they are not 100% guaranteed but for your purposes they are probably going to be just fine.

I've attached the code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <objbase.h>

int main()
{
    GUID guid;
    CoCreateGuid(&guid);

    printf("%08lX-%04hX-%04hX-%02hhX%02hhX-%02hhX%02hhX%02hhX%02hhX%02hhX%02hhX",
        guid.Data1, guid.Data2, guid.Data3,
        guid.Data4[0], guid.Data4[1], guid.Data4[2], guid.Data4[3],
        guid.Data4[4], guid.Data4[5], guid.Data4[6], guid.Data4[7]);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

This is going to return the unique name as [32 hex digits grouped into chunks of 8-4-4-4-12](http://betterexplained.com/articles/the-quick-guide-to-guids/).

Upon running the code on my machine it provided a GUID of: `CAF9B27A-AA9E-46DE-9966-C3EDBE5D674F`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Note that this works on Windows only.  There are UUID libraries that can be used for other systems.